# ROS2 spawn controllers (launch.py)

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

For my mecanum robot, i'm trying to build everything using ROS2.
Currently i'm at the point where i implemented a hardware interface class for controlling the motors and reading the sensors.

Following the documentation on ros2_control github, i'm at the point where i need to run "ros2 contol load_start_controller", where i'm testing with the diff_drive_controller before implementing a custom controller for mecanum drive.

I can't find any information on how to automatically spawn the controller in ROS2 so i don't have to run the ros2 control load_start_controller every time i launch my robot nodes.

Can the controller be defined in the URDF as we do with hardware interface or can the controller be spawned trough python launch files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374824/ros2-spawn-controllers-(launch.py)/) by [RandyD](https://answers.ros.org/users/29157/randyd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2021-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-03-30**:
You certainly can start the controller in your launch file. At the very least, anything that can be run from the commandline can be run from a python launch file by adding an `ExecuteProcess` action to your launch description. Something to the effect of:

```
return LaunchDescritpion([... ,ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_start_controller', 'differential_drive_controller'],
        output='screen'
    ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To start a controller immediately you should add a spawner node to your launch file. You can even control if controller should be started or only configured on the beginning using the flag "--stoppped" to only load and configure a controller.

```
joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="spawner",
    arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster", "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
)
```

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2022-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2